Run Full Refresh in Power BI Service with PowerShell Script
I have a Semantic Model that has implemented Incremental Refresh.
I want to create a .ps script to set him to run each week.
At this moment my script want to run just incremental and I can't do it to run in full and I don`t understand why.
Anyone has any ideea?

Part of the script:

# FULL REFRESH
Write-Host "Starting refresh operation"

# Check if the dataset exists in workspace
if ( Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $filteredWorkspaceId -Name $filteredWorkspaceName) {

      $header = 
        '{   
          "refresh": {       
                "type": "full", 
                "applyRefreshPolicy": false,
                "commitMode": "transactional",
                "maxParallelism": 8,
                "retryCount": 2                
            }
        }'


    # If the dataset exists, trigger the refresh
    $refreshSemanticModelDEV = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $urlGroups -Body ($header) -Method POST -Verbose -WarningAction Ignore 
    $refreshSemanticModelDEV

    #$refreshHystory = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method GET -Url $urlGroups -WarningAction Ignore -Body ($header)
    #$refreshHystory

}
else
{
    # If the dataset does not exist, display an error message
    Write-Host "Dataset does not exist in " $filteredWorkspaceName
}


What is the error that you are getting?

@AmilaMGunawardana I don`t receive any error, but I made him to work; but now other problem is that full refresh do not bring real data from DB (I use On-Premises gateway for SAP Hana DB).
At this moment Power BI Desktop show correct data (like in DB), but Service show me data multiplied for 64 times.
The result is same if I drop data and I rung again Full Refresh, even if I drop data then publish from desktop and do full refresh.
At this moment I think maybe it is a problem of the memory cache.
